# I'm trying to position my carousel caption on top but it's not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, caption

I'm trying to position my carousel caption on top but it's not working and I also want to the background to have a 100% width (I want it to fill the whole row of where it's placed, I don't want it to be limited to the text width size)

here's my html code

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4><span class="caption-style"> Caption goes here</span></h4> 
</div>
```

and here's my css styling

```
.caption-style {
    color:   white !important;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For carousel caption top,

you can use your top size by using margin-top

```
.carousel-caption {
    margin-top: -2em;
}
```

or you can use

```
.carousel-caption {
        top: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just style the `.carousel-caption`. To have text at the top use

```
.carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}

<div class="carousel-caption">
    <h4>Caption goes here</h4> 
</div>
```

Your `h4` should cover the whole width of the parent or is there a particular behavior that you are looking for?

Comment: I want the background to cover the width of the parent and the text to be centered in the background

Comment: top: 0 didn't work? That's strange. Anyways, I'm glad you got your question answered good luck with your project.

Comment: Awesome good to know. Next time I'm pulling my hair out I have something else to try :)